# Need to create custom Scrollbar using jquery

Tags: jquery

Hi I need to drag div in X position only in jquery, I tried this but it is dragging in x and y coordinates but I need just dragging in x

i need to drag div from position 0 to 230px.

```
$("#draggable" ).draggable({
    create: function( event, ui ) {}
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#draggable').draggable({
    axis: 'x',
    containment: [0, 0, 230, 0]
});
```

Comment: It only answers the first part, to restrict it to x-axis, it will not restrict it to 0-230px.

Comment: @RaunakKathuria I edited my answer. you can use the containment option

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$( "selector" ).draggable({ 
    axis: "x"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To restrict it to 0 to 230px, add parent container to your selector

```
<div id="containment-wrapper"> 

<div class="draggable ui-widget-content"> <p id="draggable5" class="ui-widget-header">I'm contained within my parent</p> </div>

</div>
```

give the main container a width

and add the following code

```
$( "#draggable5" ).draggable({ containment: "parent", axis: "x"});
```

Refer http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#constrain-movement